50s or 60s musical film interesting dance sequence with instruments under the floor
This film made a big impression on me and my dad and I watched it together when I was a kid. He has since died and I want to re-watch the movie.
I can't remember many other details, but I remember once scene pretty vividly.
It is a musical type film from the 50s (or perhaps early 60s) and there is a dance scene where a female performer dressed in black (I believe a brunette) is dancing on backgrounds of primary colours. Emerging from holes in the floors and walls are hands "playing" instruments like trumpets or saxophones.  
Unfortunately, I don't remember the plot or any other details about it.
It is making me feel like perhaps I imagined it!

That's a highly specific image...and it's a cracking movie.
The actress is Ann Miller and the movie is a MGM production directed by Busby Berkeley Small Town Girl from 1953 and the song is "I Gotta Hear That Beat".





Yes!!!!  Thank you so much :) The image impacted me greatly as a girl but clearly didn't help my memory.

I just watched the clip and it made me so happy! Thanks again.
